# how to install SCIP

Tags: scip

I use YALMIP which has to use SCIP to solve my problem. I don't know how to install it on my computer(Win 7).  I have download it and the install file told me to enter "make" in my computer.

Where should I enter this commend? I typed it in "matlab" and “CMD”. But it didn't work.

Comment: No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)). Thanks and announcements of appreciation etc should never be part of a good questions.
It is not impolite to leave that out but it is wasting readers time when you put it in.

Answer (score 1):

`make` is a UNIX tool. You cannot use it under Windows unless you're inside a Linux/UNIX environment like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

If you want to install SCIP on Windows you need to compile the code first, e.g. using Visual Studio.

Another possibility might be to use the precompiled binaries/executables of the previous version [SCIP 3.1.0](http://scip.zib.de/#download).

Answer (score 1):

From the [YALMIP Wiki entry SCIP](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Solvers.SCIP):

> To use the solver in YALMIP and MATLAB, a mex interface is required. YALMIP uses the interface available in the [OPTI Toolbox](http://www.i2c2.aut.ac.nz/Wiki/OPTI/index.php).